# Unknown server error occurred when processing this request when querying CosmosDB

Tags: mongodb-query, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I tried the query below but for some reason I get a `Unknown server error occurred when processing this request`. I am a bit new to mongodb but when reading the documentation for Mongodb shell and CosmosDB, all the operators listed seem supported and this look syntactically correct.

```
db.getCollection('transactions').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match:{
                bdr_date: 20181031, 
                make: { $exists: false }, 
                shard_key: '1249_2018-10', 
                time: { $gt: 2344 }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: { 
                total_sales: { 
                    $sum: { 
                        $multiply: [
                            "$sales",
                            "$units"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    ]
)
```

My CosmosDB uses MongoAPI and contains one collection named `transactions` with documents that have many keys but here are the important ones:

```
{
    "bdr_date" : INT(32),
    "time" : INT(32),
    "sales" : Double,
    "units" : INT(32),
    "shard_key" : String
}
```

There is also a key called `{ "make": INT(32) }` in some documents where we had a script that filled data holes. I only wanted documents with real data so I filtered out documents with the `"make"` key. `bdr_date` is in `yyyymmdd` format and `time` is in `HHMM` format.

The error code doesn't really say much else except for the unknown server error exception so I'm pretty stumped on what exactly I am doing wrong. Is there something simple that I am missing?

If you need more information, I'll do my best to accommodate. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Send an email to AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com with your Cosmos DB Account name, any time ranges the errors happened with, and (even better) a simple repro. For 500 errors, it often requires an investigation on the backend.

Comment: thanks. got a response quickly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sending an email to AskCosmosDB@microsoft.com, apparently there is some bug which will be fixed in the future that currently makes Cosmos return the wrong error message.

In my case, it ended up being something simple. I just forgot to put `_id` key into the `$group` operator. For my case, making `_id: null` fixed the issue.

```
db.getCollection('transactions').aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match:{
                bdr_date: 20181031, 
                make: { $exists: false }, 
                shard_key: '1249_2018-10', 
                time: { $gt: 2344 }
            }
        },
        {
            $group: { 
                _id: null,
                total_sales: { 
                    $sum: { 
                        $multiply: [
                            "$sales",
                            "$units"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    ]
)
```